# Synchronous callbacks in C

Tags: c, sockets, callback, android-source

I have multiple methods in C `DoSomething1()`, `DoSomething2()`, ..., `DoSomethingN()` that request for some data. These methods can be called concurrently.
The data resides in a different process and currently the communication between the current process and that other process is done using a socket.

How can I create a synchronous callback `GetSpecialValue()` that requests the data using the aforementioned socket and then, when the socket replies, returns the answer back to the specific `DoSomethingN()` that has requested it?

Keep in mind that I have a lot of methods that work with a single socket and pass requests that their reply should return to the specific method that initiated the call. Those methods work in different threads.

```
int DoSomethingN(int id) {
    int returnValue = GetSpecialValue(id);
    return returnValue;
}

int GetSpecialValue(int id) {
    SendToProcessViaSocket(id);
    int returnValue = ReceiveSocketAnswer();
    return returnValue;
}
```

I know that some people use `libevent` for callbacks, but I don't think that you can return new parameters when the event is called. Also, it's async and isn't part of the **AOSP build**..

Thanks!

Comment: Things work synchronously by default - why do you need to do anything? Simply send the request, then receive the response...

Comment: It sounds you need to use thread locking, you can create a lock which is taken out by the function GetSpecialValue(), and gets released by DoSomethingN() functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to lock the thread after the request was passed
and then, add the lock to vector that was visible by the thread that handles the requests socket.

```
std::tuple<int, pthread_mutex_t *, pthread_cond_t *, bool *> callbackData;
pthread_mutex_t *reqMutexLock = (pthread_mutex_t *)malloc(sizeof(*reqMutexLock));
pthread_cond_t *reqCondition = (pthread_cond_t *)malloc(sizeof(*reqCondition));
bool *state = (bool *)malloc(sizeof(*state));

(*reqMutexLock) = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
(*reqCondition) = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
(*state) = false;

int callbackId = rand();

callbackData = std::make_tuple(callbackId, reqMutexLock, reqCondition, state);

pthread_mutex_lock(reqMutexLock);
SendRequest(callbackId, id);
while (!(*state)) {
    pthread_cond_wait(reqCondition, reqMutexLock);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(reqMutexLock);
pthread_mutex_destroy(reqMutexLock);
free(reqMutexLock);
free(reqCondition);
...
```

When the response has returned from the socket, 
the response would be saved in a responses vector and the lock fetched from the vector and released.

```
...
response = ReceiveResponse();
responsesList.push_back(response);

...
reqMutexLock = std::get<1>(callbackDataList[foundIndex]);
reqCondition = std::get<2>(callbackDataList[foundIndex]);
state = std::get<3>(callbackDataList[foundIndex]);

pthread_mutex_lock(reqMutexLock);
(*state) = true;
pthread_cond_broadcast(reqCondition);
pthread_mutex_unlock(reqMutexLock);
...
```

After the lock was released, the thread would continue and ask for the result, that will be returned from the vector.

```
...
return GetResponse(callbackId);
```